# Residual Plot: Is the linear model appropriate for this dataset?

Tags: r, regression, linear-regression

I am working on a linear regression analysis and in order to verify that the linear model was appropriate for my data, I produced a residual plot and found what looks like "patterns". I learned that in order for the linear model to be appropriate, the residual plot has to appear like a random scatter of points. I am confused if these count as a random scatter of points.

My plot and corresponding residual plot

[image]

Comment: To me it looks like there would be no relation between Average Sleep and Average Screen Time. On the left plot the points look pretty random to me. A linear modell would be a good choice if you'd expect sleeptime to increase/decrease with every additional unit of screentime (for the same amount, no matter if screentime increases from 1 to 2 or 10 to 11). If this was not the case you would see some systematic pattern in the residual-plot (for example an overestimation on large screentime values and an underestimation on lower ones).

Comment: I concur with the last post. I'd add that at this stage, learning more about the linear model and how to diagnose it, away from your data, is more important. Have a look at this in depth example, one you can follow along with 
http://r-statistics.co/Linear-Regression.html. Do you have any other variables you could use in your model? e.g. Age, Gender etc. Also, its typically better to work first not with the average data, but with the raw data. You will be able to capture your variation better. For general statistics, try https://stats.stackexchange.com/ for help

Comment: If a data scatterplot does not show that most of the data is on (or close to) a straight line, a straight line will not model such data.